# How to pass extra parameters in in handle_text in rasa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am creating a chatbot using `RASA` and `Flask`

I have a strange requirement where for the same question I have to configure 2 different responses based on request.

In request there is a key `customer` it can be 1 or 0.

Say I have a question:

`what is refund policy?`

If the question is asked by customer(where key value is 1)

it will return **You will get refund in 3 days**

else it will return **You will get refund in 7 days**

So I am stuck how to pass this `customer` value in `handle_text` which is generating response for my Question.

Is there a way to do this in `Rasa`?

My Code:

```
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_core.utils importEndpointConfig
from flask import FLASK, request
import json

nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter(NLU_MODEL)
action_endpoint = EndpointConfig(url=ACTION_ENDPOINT) 
agent = Agent.load(DIALOG_MODEL, interpreter=nlu_interpreter, action_endpoint=action_endpoint)

@app.route("/chatbot", methods=["POST"])
def bot():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    msg = data["msg"]  # the question by user
    is_customer = data["customer"]

    response = agent.handle_text(msg, sender_id=data["user_id"])

    return json.dumps(response[0]["text"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure that action in the action files and run a separate action server to handle that for you.

For example, inside the run method of your custom method, you could get the slot value of customer and then depending on that slot value, you can return required message.

```
      def run(self,
           dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
           tracker: Tracker,
           domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

      customer = tracker.get_slot('customer')
      if customer:
          dispatcher.utter_message("You will get refund in 3 days.")
      else:
          dispatcher.utter_message("You will get refund in 7 days.")
```

Doc link: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/actions/#custom-actions

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't have `customer` as entity so I can not get it using `tracker.get_slot`. If you check the example given in link `show me a Mexican restaurant` which has  *mexican* as cuisine so it can be obtained from `tracker.get_slot()` My case is different I get if user is customer or not from different key as shown in above question

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar your *slot* doesn't need to be an *entity*. And you can set slot values however it pleases you.

Comment: Ok I was not aware of that. But How can I set the slot? If you see I'm using `agent.handle_text(msg, sender_id=data["user_id"])` to get response from Action Server. How can pass value of customer in it?

Comment: How are you determining the value of `customer`?

Comment: I am receiving it from request. See I edited the question. `is_customer = data["customer"]`